# Is it possible to check if two binary trees are isomorphic in linear time?

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm

Let's say all the node values are the same. We'd like to know if two such binary trees are isomorphic. Flipping right and left children is allowed.

Ok someone asked me what I have done. Here it is. I did the naive approach.

```
bool isIsomorphic(Node* a, Node* b) {
   if(a == b) return true;
   if(!a || !b) return false;

   return isIsomorphic(a->left, b->left) && isIsomorphic(a->right, b->right)
       || isIsomorphic(a->left, b->right) && isIsomorphic(a->right, b->left);

}
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Did you try?

Comment: It is possible. But SO is not a service for stuff like "i need a solution for this problem". Show you're approach and the problems resulting from it and you'll get help

Comment: Why wouldn't it be? Am I overlooking something obvious?

Comment: @erickson: It's certainly not obvious to me how to do this in the required time bound.  One technique would be to show how each tree can be canonicalised in O(n) -- but how can the sibling subtree comparisons be cached so as to avoid worst-case O(n) time per comparison?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. This algorithm is due to Aho--Hopcroft--Ullman.

Process the trees bottom up, level by level. Each node is labeled with a positive integer between 1 and the number of nodes on its level that, within its level, identifies its isomorphism class. The two trees are isomorphic if and only if they end up with the same label.

When we process a level, the nodes one level deeper have already been processed. To compute labels for this level, we start with a bunch of unordered pairs {L, R} where L is the left child's label, and R is the right child's label (0 for null children), and we assign each of these a positive integer. This is done by radix sorting the pairs (one coordinate at a time) and then comparing elements that are adjacent in the sorted order. The labels in sorted order are nondecreasing; they increase whenever two consecutive pairs are distinct.